# New Zealand SMC Job Search Visa to Residence Visa

Tags: visa, immigration, new-zealand, skilled-migration

My wife is the primary applicant and our SMC Visa application got lodged in July 2019.
Since we do not have a Job Offer and we are offshore, She is eligible for a SMC Job Search Visa.

My Question is:

1. Once she gets the Job Offer, how much time does it take to move from SMC Job Search Visa to Resident Visa?
2. Do we need to produce the Job Offer Letter to INZ, then they move the SMC Job Search Visa to Resident Visa?
3. What are the criterion to move to Resident Visa?

Can anybody put some light on these queries?

Thanks and Regards